# Rails app always returns "Unprocessable Entity" to Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, http, kotlin

I'm trying to connect an Android App to a RoR App so it can create a new user, but no matter what I do I always get "Unprocessable Entity". Right now I'm using Kotlin instead of Java.

**users_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    render json: @article
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: api_v1_article_url(@user)
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      render json: @article
    else
      render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
  end

  private

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.permit(:name, :lastName, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
internal inner class UserCreator : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {
        lateinit var response: StringBuffer
        try{
            val mURL = URL("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/users")
            val reqParam = JSONObject()
            val holder = JSONObject()
            reqParam.put("name", params[0])
            reqParam.put("lastName", params[1])
            reqParam.put("email", params[2])
            reqParam.put("password", params[3])
            reqParam.put("password_confirmation", params[4])
            holder.put("user", reqParam)
            with(mURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
                requestMethod = "POST"
                val wr = OutputStreamWriter(getOutputStream());
                wr.write(holder.toString());
                wr.flush();
                println("URL : $url")
                println("Response Code : $responseCode")
                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
                    response = StringBuffer()
                    var inputLine = it.readLine()
                    while (inputLine != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine)
                        inputLine = it.readLine()
                    }
                    it.close()
                }
            }
        }catch(e: RuntimeException){
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        return response.toString()
    }
}
```

Someone knows what am I doing wrong? I understand that I should send a JSONObject() with the POST request but it is not allowing me to do that, I can only send Strings.

**ERROR**

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-27 20:26:09 -0600
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"{\"name\":\"Test\",\"lastName\":\"Tester\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"password\":\"foobar\",\"password_confirmation\":\"foobar\"}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Unpermitted parameter: :{"name":"Test","lastName":"Tester","email":"test@test.com","password":"foobar","password_confirmation":"foobar"}
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:11
  User Exists (3.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:11
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:11
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 174ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 38.6ms)
```

Comment: Can you print the error from your server logs when you post the message?

Comment: Of course! @JayDorsey, Done.

Comment: @JayDorsey I just removed the unprocessable entity status and it seems that the post requests are being received as blank. Although I can see the data I type in the android app inside the RoR CMD...

Comment: You reference `article_params` in one part of your code, but there's no mention of that method anywhere. It looks like your params aren't being filtered correctly. You'll see the `unpermitted parameter` line in your log file that shows all your params are being filtered for some reason. Are you sure your code is correct (that you shared/posted)?

Comment: @JayDorsey I understand that I forgot to change that part of the code but it the 'acticle' attributes doesn't disturb the create function.

Comment: Actually, the closer I look at this the more this looks like an issue w/ how you're sending the request across so I don't know that I can help much. The rails side is doing the things that it's supposed to. Your log info & what's in your code doesn't seem to line up with what I'd expect (a json nested as something like `{user: { name: 'foo'.... }}`, but your strong params don't look for a top level `user` key either so. Is the error message in sync with the code? I'm leaning towards this being an issue w/ how you crafted the URL vs a Rails/strong params issue but it's hard to tell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185862/discussion-between-jay-dorsey-and-aldo).

Answer (score 0):

So... After looking at my Android App code I realized that I was sending just a string to the RoR App instead of a Json object, so I changed it using the deprecated classes "DefaultHttpClient()", "HttpPost()", etc... (I don't like using deprecated classes but...) and it finlly worked! Many thanks to Jay Dorsey for the time spent with this problem.